# Zend_Auth expiration

Tags: zend-framework

Anyone knows why my `Zend_Auth` expires for a specific time and how can I set/extend it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$seconds = 3600; //one hour
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$namespace->setExpirationSeconds($seconds);
```

Comment: Is Zend_Auth also a Zend_Session?